# Creating Next button in Java Swing (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have five buttons in my current GUI named Browse, Unzip, Convert, Copy and Zip. First event is browse and by using that button I upload a zipped file and then click on unzip to unzip that file followed by convert and copy buttons and finally Zip the file again by clicking on Zip button. I have kept them in a sequential order and click on them one by one but I want to put these actions as Browse, Next, Next, Next and Finish button. So please help me out in achieving this task.

My Java Swing (Netbeans) code looks like:

```
public class MyClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private void browseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
//Code here 
} 
private void unzipButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
//Code here  
} 
private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
//Code here 
} 
private void copyButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
//Code here 
} 
private void zipButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
//Code here 
} 
}
```

Thanking you!

Comment: *"So please help me out in achieving this task."*  So please ask a question.  Make it a specific question.  As to the Netbeans code, throw it away and start again.  1) Give the class a sensible name like `ArchiveManagerGUI` 2) Don't extend frame, simply keep a reference to one. 3) Add anonymous inner listeners - one for each button. --  To achieve this, I might use a `CardLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a classic wizard application with [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

You could create a base panel in the BorderLayout.SOUTH position of your JFrame that would have your action buttons and have a number of panels added to your main panel being managed by CardLayout.

See [Creating Wizard Dialogs with Java Swing](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/)

Comment: Thanks for the links and suggestions. I'll go through these links.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you just need one `JFrame` and one `JPanel`, Every click or step will change the content of `JPanel`. But the the main class containing the `JFrame` or the one extends the `JFrame` will have reference to the file which you are working with.

P.S. This cannot be achieved efficiently by any pre made GUI builder. But, the programatic solution is pretty simple.

Something like this : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/

Comment: "*Every click or step will change the content of `JPanel`."*  Why not try that brilliant 'new' layout known as `CardLayout`?  Perfect for this use-case.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Can't agree anymore! I just completely skipped that lol

Comment: @Owl Thanks for answer. I'm going through the link given by you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `CardLayout` and adding multiple `JPanel`s to it. Typically, I create my own `JPanel` subclasses to hold the controls then add them to a `JFrame`, in this case with a `CardLayout` set. Your "Next" button can change which JPanel is shown...in fact, with some ingenuity and multiple layout managers, you only need one "Next" button.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll use CardLayout.